# Advanced Custom Fields do not work after the loop WP

Tags: wordpress

I use Advanced Custom Fields in my template. After the cycle, the fields are no longer displayed. Everything works fine before the cycle

```html
           <?php the_field('Text_fisrt_sec'); ?> // the code works
          <?php 
              $args = array(
                     'post_type' => 'project',
                     'publish' => true,
                     'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
                 );
              
              query_posts($args);

              if ( have_posts() ) : 
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

           ?>
           
          <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
           
                        <?php 
              endwhile;
              endif;
              wp_reset_postdata();
              ?>
              
              <?php the_field('Text_fisrt_sec'); ?> // Here the code does not work anymore
```

Comment: Where did you code?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `wp_reset_query();` instead of `wp_reset_postdata();`

```
<?php $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'project',
    'publish' => true,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
 );

    query_posts($args);

    if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    ?>

        <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>

     <?php
    endwhile;
    endif;
```

> wp_reset_query();

```
    ?>

<?php the_field('Text_fisrt_sec'); ?>
```